# Can't remove apostrophe when using split() in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, split, fetch

I have a bad idea to fetch some .js file from site in to my VCS environment for using later this array in some examples.

```
const a = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("https://eloquentjavascript.net/code/journal.js");
    const events = await response.text();
    return events;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}

  const count = await a();
  let c = count.slice(16,6786).split(" ").join("");
  let JOURNAL = c.split(/\r?\n/).filter(element => element);
  console.log(JOURNAL)
```

I try a lot of things - nothing, it seems very simple, but I have a problem, Houston:

```
[
  '{"events":["carrot","exercise","weekend"],"squirrel":false},',
  '{"events":["bread","pudding","brushedteeth","weekend","touchedtree"],"squirrel":false},',
  '{"events":["carrot","nachos","brushedteeth","cycling","weekend"],"squirrel":false},',
  '{"events":["brusselsprouts","icecream","brushedteeth","computer","weekend"],"squirrel":false},',
  '{"events":["potatoes","candy","brushedteeth","exercise","weekend","dentist"],"squirrel":false},', 
...
]
```

This apostrophe ( ' ) between values. How can i handle it.
But if:

```
console.log(JOURNAL[0])
{"events":["carrot","exercise","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
```

Maybe I don't understand something, I just want create array with variables from response.text() Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried something like just using replaceAll and removing them **c = c.replaceAll("'","")**?

Comment: there are no apostrophes. If you mean commas, there are none either, the array uses commas to separate elements but they are not part of the data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i can't use it, i do something wrong again: 

`TypeError: c.split(...).replaceAll is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to remove the last comma `,` in each string with `slice(0, -1)`, then you can use `JSON.parse`

```js
const data = [
  '{"events":["carrot","exercise","weekend"],"squirrel":false},',
  '{"events":["bread","pudding","brushedteeth","weekend","touchedtree"],"squirrel":false},',
  '{"events":["carrot","nachos","brushedteeth","cycling","weekend"],"squirrel":false},',
  '{"events":["brusselsprouts","icecream","brushedteeth","computer","weekend"],"squirrel":false},',
  '{"events":["potatoes","candy","brushedteeth","exercise","weekend","dentist"],"squirrel":false},', 
]

const result = data.map(item => JSON.parse(item.slice(0, -1)))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: It seems that I have not yet fully understood this, but it seems to me that I love you!

Comment: You are welcome, If we try to `JSON.parse` the text directly it will gives an error because of the last `comma` can't be parsed, So we need to remove it first by `slice(0, -1)` then parse the string.